# Is there a way to place something under the body tag with a random class?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, tags

A body tag in my document has a random class each time a file is generated. I want to find this body tag with Python and place something under it (another tag with some attributes). How can I find a body with a class I don't really know?

EDIT (code I tried):

```py
try:
    html = open("new_html_file.html", "w+")
    soup = Soup(html, features="html.parser")
    body = soup.find('body')
    button = soup.new_tag('button')
    button['class'] = "cupid-blue"
    button['onclick'] = "location.href=\'index.html\';"
    button.insert(0, NavigableString("Spis Tre&#347;ci"))
    body.insert_after(button)
    br_line = soup.new_tag('br')
    button.insert_after(br_line)

    html.write(str(soup.prettify()))
    html.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("COULDN'T ADD BUTTON TO THE SCRIPT! -> " + str(e))
    html.close()
```

Comment: find other method to recognize this element. Maybe it has `class` or other attribute. Or maybe its parent has unique `id`, `class` or other attribute. Or maybe you can count elements and use `item[index]` to recognize it. There is no answer without showing real HTML. But event then it may not have solution. BTW: if you means `<body>` then you should have only one tag `<body>` in all HTML and you shouldn't have problem to get `<body>`

Comment: Yes, but the thing is that the body tag has a class. Every time the file is generated (I generate it from Google Docs), the class is random. I tried `bs4` to do that but it seems it can't find it. I will update the question with the code I tried.

Comment: I don't understad what you try to do. Can't you do `find("body")` to get `<body>` ? You don't need `class` to get `<body>`.

Comment: I tested your code and when I `print()` HTML then I see `<button>` after `<body>`. I don't understand what is your problem. You don't need `class` to find object which is only one in all code. Maybe first check what you have in file and in soup after reading file - maybe there is no body.

Comment: I got an `AttributeError` saying that the `body` variable does not have `insert_after` function so I thought it can't find the body tag inside the HTML document.

Comment: if you use `w+` then it delete all in file before `soup` read it and then it can't find `body` in empty file and `find('body')` gives `None` and you can get `NoneType` does not have `insert_after`

Comment: downvotes can inform other people that this question is boring. OR it is basic problem which could be resolved with basic knowledge or with small debuging (ie, using `print()` to see values in variables). OR this problem was so many times on Stackoveflow so you could find solution in other answers using Google. OR you didn't add needed information to resolve problem. In many situations it means this question is not useful for next generations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `"w+"` in `open()` - it deletes text in file and `Soup` reads empty string.

At start you should open it only for reading and close it.

And at the end you should open it for writing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from bs4 import NavigableString

try:
    # only for reading
    html = open("test.html").read()

    soup = Soup(html, features="html.parser")
    #print(soup.prettify())  # test what is in soup

    body = soup.find('body')
    button = soup.new_tag('button')
    button['class'] = "cupid-blue"
    button['onclick'] = "location.href=\'index.html\';"
    button.insert(0, NavigableString("Spis Treści"))
    body.insert_after(button)
    br_line = soup.new_tag('br')
    button.insert_after(br_line)
    #print(soup.prettify())  # test what is in soup

    # only for writing
    html = open("test.html", "w")
    html.write(soup.prettify())
    html.close()

except Exception as e:
    print("COULDN'T ADD BUTTON TO THE SCRIPT! ->", e)
    html.close()
```

Comment: Thanks and do you know what can I do about the special characters like: ą, ć, ę, ż, ź, etc.? They get replaced with this weird question mark and I want to be in ascii code or like change the encoding of them?

Comment: first: ASCII means chars with codes 0-127 and there is no place for Polish chars (or any other native chars) and it has to display `?`.

Comment: In some text editor you can set `utf-8` when you open file to display it correctly. Pages usually use encoding `utf-8` but you have to use `<meta chars="utf-8">` in HTML to display it correctly. If you use Windows then it uses `latin2` (old web pages) or `cp1250` (filenames) or `cp852` (console) and it can also display `?` - and you may have to use ie. `print(text.encode('utf-8').decode('latin2'))` to display convert `utf-8` to `latin2` before printing. In Google you could also find how to use registers to change default encoding in console to use `utf-8` (or `60001`)